# Should I sell a custom built mountain bike as a full bike or break it into parts?

Tags: build

I have a bike that I have built up over the last few years. It's a good bike and works as it is, with a good quality components. However, I want to sell it. Is it best to sell it broken down as parts or as a full bike?

Comment: The time needed to break it apart and individually sell, may  outweigh any gains. Would 5 hours extra be worth the extra money? Also, what about unsold parts?

Comment: Donate it to the local bike recycling group.

Comment: I unfortunately live in a capitalist system therefore I will sell it not give it away on this occasion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may depend on the overall age of the bike but I would guess that in most cases it's better to sell it as a whole. If the bike only consists of rather standard components that one could easily buy at a LBS, then they wouldn't make high prices and the additional work to break it all down and maybe set them all on on ebay separately may not be worth the money.

I can imagine only two cases where it may be better to sell it in parts or at least to sell some parts separately:

- You have one or more high priced components on it that are still nearly new and unused, or
- there are some (older) components that are no longer available from the manufacturers but make a high price even when bought second hand as they are required to repair an otherwise still working bike (imagine 7-speed shifters from the former higher priced component groups such as Shimano XT to replace a damaged one).

Answer (score 3):

Based on my experiences and assuming that you plan to use eBay, I would most definitely sell it in bits for this reason: No one will be searching for your custom bike config, so you'll only ever receive interest on a general level, and never benefit from targeted bargain/collectors frenzy :)

eBay is busy enough now that most items you can think of listing will have a specific audience. There WILL be someone searching for a [insert you particular chainset] or [insert your part-used front tyre] and that person will develop a vested interest in your item because they "need" it to complete their own custom bike, or to replace an exact part on their beloved shop-bought complete bike.

I've done this a lot, both as a buyer and a seller. eBayers will always bid over the top for something they "just want".

Comment: hmmmm.... completely opposing viewpoints there. I would have been inclined to agree but these days I would agree with Benedikt because of the time it takes to break the bike down and sell everything individually.

Comment: I think it depends how and where you want to sell it. If you're going to eBay, I would say that individual pieces would work better, but if you're trying to sell it locally, then you might be better off selling it as a whole bike.   Also if you're selling individual pieces it's probably likely that you'll end up with a few left over bits that you might have trouble selling to anybody.  But many bike shops buy (or specialize in) old/used parts, so it's usually possible to get them off your hands if you need the room.

Comment: @kibbee Yea totally agree, stripping only works well on eBay.